# Each microservice has to implement authentication and authorization or it's better one centerized to deal with it?

Tags: java, node.js, spring, security, microservices

This question is not about what use to securing the microservices like Oauth2 or JWT, but what is better strategy for deal it with it.

What should we choose? Please, if has another tip will be welcome!

1. An authentication and authorization service (AuthService) isolated out of microservices:
   Microservice must call AuthService before process the request. (like a Middleware)
2. Microservice has to do its own authentication and authorization.
3. The AuthService always recieves the calls and do the transference for microservice (like a Gateway)
4. Implement a Backend For Frontend (BFF) and itself do it auth and calls for the others microservices.

This last one, some friend have talked about to me buuut... On case that you have to scaling 1 or 2 microservices, you have to scaling vertically the BFF too. That's a weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

Normally authentication and authorization is at microservice level. But authentication service/database should be outside and internal to microservice, enable cache to minimise calls to Auth service and to minimise API latency.

Comment: Ok, but  lets supose that I have 5 microservices and 1 frontend (SPA), and the authentication is JWT. 

Every microservice must to have the same secret for JWT?
For authorization I think I agree because its a single domain to control.

These questions that I am not confortable to implement it! lol

Comment: It’s upto you. It ll work with single JWT n also with one to one JWT.